# upgrade from 15.04 to 15.10! two main problems please help

Tags: upgrade, 15.10, update-manager

so far after update everything works except! in some plaeses it displays boxes insead of words meinly in the title bars, need help with that. And... this is a biggy, u try and update system or check for updates, it starts checking then says check you internet conection then stops. really need help with that one.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztqLE.png)

Comment: If you are so new to Ubuntu, I suggest installing an LTS version. For 15.10 you probably need to install a video driver.

Comment: i have the right driver, not new just first time here. went from 14.04 to 15.04 everything fine until i installed 15.10. i tried update in a command line and got 4 of these errors at the end.

Comment: W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 15.04 _Vivid Vervet_ - Release amd64 (20150422)/dists/vivid/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

Comment: i ran sudo apt-cdrom to see what it would say and ill post it here, but i do not have a cd rom.

Comment: sexyjae@sexyjae-Q551LN:~$ sudo apt-cdrom
apt 1.0.10.2ubuntu1 for amd64 compiled on Oct  5 2015 15:55:05
Usage: apt-cdrom [options] command

apt-cdrom is a tool to add CDROM's to APT's source list. The
CDROM mount point and device information is taken from apt.conf
and /etc/fstab.

Commands:
   add - Add a CDROM
   ident - Report the identity of a CDROM

Comment: Options:
  -h   This help text
  -d   CD-ROM mount point
  -r   Rename a recognized CD-ROM
  -m   No mounting
  -f   Fast mode, don't check package files
  -a   Thorough scan mode
  --no-auto-detect Do not try to auto detect drive and mount point
  -c=? Read this configuration file
  -o=? Set an arbitrary configuration option, eg -o dir::cache=/tmp

Comment: Disable the CD-ROM in your software sources.

Comment: might sound stupid but how do i do that?

Comment: System Settings -> Software & Updates

Comment: i understand that but like i said alot of words are displayed as boxes

Comment: kinda like invalid key strokes

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type `software-properties-gtk`
Change the download location to Main Server and try again.
Then open terminal and type:

```
ping 4.2.2.4
```

If you see:

[image]

Your connection is OK.

For upgrade, see http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade.

Comment: did not work sir

Comment: i mean i did all of that but once done updates still say check internet.

Comment: [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ztqLE.png